# How do I comment out lines of code in bash?

Tags: bash

I need to comment out 3 lines in an apache config:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    <- 
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    <- 
    #RewriteRule . index.php [L]            <-
```

for 1000 machines.

How can I comment out the last 3 lines using bash commands over ssh for all these machines?

### Sample Input

```
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    <- 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    <- 
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]            <-
```

### Sample Output

```
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    <- 
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    <- 
    #RewriteRule . index.php [L]            <-
```

Comment: What criteria are you using to pick which three lines? As posed, this is too broad to be answered, IMO.

Comment: Is the config file the same on all of them? If so you could just copy the new config instead of patching each of the old ones

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: You can use `sed` to find a string/word and replace it with a new word

Comment: You should start using an existing configuration management system instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: @Cyrus added, please check

Comment: @chepner such as?

Comment: [Puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)) or [Ansible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_(software)), e.g.

Comment: (...or [Chef](https://www.chef.io/); as someone who's worked with all three (after rolling-my-own in years prior), it's the only one that's not made me tear my hair out down to needing to implement features that should be built-in. Then again, the other half of the team where I got my experience with Puppet is now the Puppet Labs CTO, so clearly not everyone had the same takeaway).

Comment: `sed '/<- $/{s/^[[:space:]]\+/&#/}' file` ;-)

Comment: @Cyrus: LOL! Those arrows aren't part of the file. They were added by the OP to point to the lines of interest.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following sed for comment out the lines:

```
sed '
    s/^RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-[fd]/#&/
    s/^RewriteRule \. index.php \[L\]/#&/
' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to comment *the last three lines* of each file, you should probably be using `ed`:

```
ed file <<END
$;#
-2;#
s/[^[:blank:]]/#&/
+s
+s
wq
END
```

Demo:

```
#!/bin/sh
f=$(mktemp)

trap 'rm "$f"' EXIT

cat >"$f"  <<END
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    <- 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    <- 
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]            <- 
END

ed "$f" <<END >/dev/null
$;#
-2;#
s/[^[:blank:]]/#&/
+s
+s
wq
END

cat "$f"
```

Output:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    <- 
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    <- 
    #RewriteRule . index.php [L]            <-
```